How to login as the user (created using Ansible) inside a virtual machine created using Vagrant?
I have created a virtual machine using Vagrant, a user inside it (using Ansible), and configured the SSH keys (also using Ansible).
Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"

  config.vm.define "vm1" do |vm1|
    vm1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.11"
    vm1.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  end
end

Start the virtual machine
vagrant up

Following are the Ansible inventory and playbook:
inventory.ini
vagrant@192.168.20.11 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/edith/vagrant/servers/.vagrant/machines/vm1/virtualbox/private_key ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes'

I created the public/private key using ssh-keygen.

private key: ~/.ssh/ansible
public key: ~/.ssh/ansible.pub

$ sudo cat ~/.ssh/ansible.pub
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIGXCAw8uJh10KraQm1xoI7umz+gho2xs5mPp477TnslF ansible

The following playbook creates a user with username simone, configures SSH for this user, and gives it the sudo privileges.
site.yml
---

- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:

  - name: create simone user
    user:
      name: simone
      groups: root
      create_home: yes # Ensure the home directory is created

  - name: debug public key path
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/edith/.ssh/ansible.pub') }}"
  
  - name: add ssh key for simone
    tags: always
    authorized_key:
      user: simone
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/edith/.ssh/ansible.pub') }}"
      exclusive: yes
        
  - name: add sudoers file for simone
    tags: always
    copy:
      src: sudoer_simone
      dest: /etc/sudoers.d/simone
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0440

I can manually login using user simone in the Vagrant virtual machine vm1
$ vagrant ssh vm1

vagrant@ubunt-focal:~$ sudo su - simone
$ whoami
simone

$ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIGXCAw8uJh10KraQm1xoI7umz+gho2xs5mPp477TnslF ansible

Note that the public key is added in the authorized_keys file in the virtual machine.
However, when I try to login directly using ssh in my local machine, without logging in the virtual machine, I get an error.
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/ansible simone@192.168.20.11
The authenticity of host '192.168.20.11 (192.168.20.11)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:N03pqpEeG5wyEDZDkpqCALvIgosGHJ4smZUpYNURSG4.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/edith/.ssh/known_hosts).
Received disconnect from 192.168.20.11 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 192.168.20.11 port 22


The problem was with the ownership of the private key.
The private key ~/.ssh/ansible has the ownership of root, so I need to run the command with sudo.
$ ls ~/.ssh
-rw------- 1 root  root   399 May  8 18:29  ansible

$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/ansible simone@192.168.20.11

